# React: Check if key is unique

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react, i'm wondering if there is a way to test if a react key is unique. I have an array of albums i'm displaying, that are being pulled from a mongodb. The way that the db is setup, the database can contain duplicate entries, and yes, it has to be this way, and no i'm not looking for a way to remove duplicates in the database query. Looking to do this in react.

As you scroll down the page, The client loads in 20 results from the db at a time, grabbing the next 20 results based on a user generated query as you keep scrolling. Eventually, you will run into these duplicates, and react generates a unique key warning, as the unique key is an ID string.

```
this.props.data.map( album => {
  album.cover = (album.images[0]) ? album.images[0].url : null

  return <Album data={album} key={album.sid} />
})
```

**I'm wondering if there is a way to test the `album.sid` property against react key's that have already been rendered, and if the key already has been rendered, don't render the component and move onto the next one.**

Comment: i was hoping to not integrate redux (overkill) but honestly if it will solve this issue i'll do it lol. but how would the reducer check the already loaded results against the incoming results? Could you post an answer with a mock example?

Comment: You don't necessarily need Redux. As far as I know you can't get a component's key, it's an internal property for React itself to use. Not sure how you're adding the new results, but if you're appending them to a list in the parent for example then just add a simple conditional append rather than appending the 20 new results all at once, .e.g. for each of the new 20 results, loop through the existing ones and see if it's already there. if so, continue to next new result without appending it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter duplicates either in the action creator (or the place where the results from the API call is returned if you are not using Redux), the reducer, or in the component if you still want to keep it in the Redux state for whatever reasons.

An O(n) duplicate filter algorithm would be:

```
const seen = new Set();
const uniqueData = data.filter(({ sid }) => {
  if (seen.has(sid)) {
    return false;
  }
  seen.add(sid);
  return true;
});
```

If you decided to do this at the component level, you may want to consider using some [memoization library](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) so that the filtering is only re-computed if the `data` has changed when the component re-renders.

Comment: ahh this is perfect! I just roughly integrated this into my loop and it works exactly how i need it to. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this comment from my (deleted) comment about redux:

> but how would the reducer check the already loaded results against the incoming results? Could you post an answer with a mock example?

Use a hash table:

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  byId: [],
  byHash: {}
}

export default function (state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ALBUM:
      return {
        ...state,
        byId: state.byId.includes(action.payload.id)
          ? [ ...state.byId ]
          : [ ...state.byId, action.payload.id ],
        byHash: {
          ...state.byHash,
          [action.payload.id]: action.payload
        }
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Your Component:

```
this.props.albumIds.map( id => {
  let album = this.props.albums[id]
  album.cover = (album.images[0]) ? album.images[0].url : null

  return <Album data={album} key={album.sid} />
})
```

Which assumes a `mapStateToProps` like:

```
{
   albumIds: state.albums.byId,
   albums: state.albums.byHash
}
```